# desktop icons not showing

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop

I recently started my laptop with ubuntu 18.04 and it's desktop icons were not showing.[image]
Then suddenly screen went blank and some warnings and errors were shown for some secs which I wasn't able to read. Then it rebooted and after starting icons were showing but it prompted that system problem is detected, d you want to report? I reported the problem. What can be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, Take a look at this and see if it helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141696/desktop-icons-disappeared-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: How did it go??

Comment: Desktop icons were showing later but it was showing an error message constantly for which I tried another solution to delete error files and that worked.